# Is it possible to conditionally assign the value of Required in @RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have 2 @RequestParam parameters in my Controller. I want to set the Required value of both the parameters based on a Condition. The condition could be like, if one of the parameter is passed, the other has to passed. So set the required of other as true and vice-versa. Otherwise set both false if none of the parameters are passed.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

@GetMapping("/test")
public void test(@RequestParam(value = "a", required = (b !=null) String a, 
@RequestParam(value = "b", required = (a !=null) )  String b,) {
     {

     }

}
```

The syntax of using the variable name inside @RequestParam() is wrong, but I wanted to explain what I want.

Comment: No you cannot. You could create an object, bind both variables and create a separate validator for that. But it won't work with simple parameters.

Comment: Why not create a bean and deffer the work to it? Then you could have the getter method to preform your check. myBean.getA and myBean.getB each containing their appropriate logic

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using one of the 2 following ways:

1. Using Spring AOP and create a surrounding aspect for that request
   mapping
2. Using HandlerInterceptorAdapter to intercept the requests for a given URI

**1. Using Spring AOP**

Create an annotation like the following:

```java
public @interface RequestParameterPairValidation {

}
```

Then you can annotate your request mapping method with it:

```java
@GetMapping("/test")
@RequestParameterPairValidation
public void test(
   @RequestParam(value = "a", required = false) String a, 
   @RequestParam(value = "b", required = false)  String b) {
      // API code goes here...
}
```

Create an aspect around the annotation. Something like:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class RequestParameterPairValidationAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(x.y.z.RequestParameterPairValidation) && execution(public * *(..))")
    public Object time(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object[] requestMappingArgs = joinPoint.getArgs();
        String a = (String) requestMappingArgs[0];
        String b = (String) requestMappingArgs[1];

        boolean requestIsValid = //... execute validation logic here

        if (requestIsValid) {
           return joinPoint.proceed();
        } else {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal request");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it would be a good option to return `400 BAD REQUEST` here since the request was not valid. Depends on the context, of course, but this is a general rule of thumb to start with.

**2. Using HandlerInterceptorAdapter**

Create a new interceptor mapping to your desired URI (in this case `/test`):

```java
@Configuration  
public class CustomInterceptor extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {  

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
       registry
         .addInterceptor(new CustomRequestParameterPairInterceptor())
         .addPathPatterns("/test");
    }
}
```

Define the logic for validation inside the custom interceptor:

```java
public class CustomRequestParameterPairInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Object obj, Exception exception) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Object obj, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Object handler) throws Exception {
       // Run your validation logic here
    }
}
```

I would say the 2nd option is the best one since you can directly control the answer of the request. In this case it might be a `400 BAD REQUEST`, or anything else that makes more sense in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Optional here in an intelligent manner here like this:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
@RequestParameterPairValidation
public void test(@RequestParam("a") Optional<String> a,
    @RequestParam("b") Optional<String> b){


    String aVal = a.isPresent() ? a.get() : null;
    String bVal = b.isPresent() ? b.get() : null;

    //go for service call here based on your logic
}
```

I hope this works for your requirement.

Comment: I might be wrong in this assumption, but I would say that the question was more related to an eventual error return from the API call if the a/b do not meet the mutual exclusion requirement. Using Optional<?> there would only give you a a semantic way to know if the value is there or not. It doesn't take care of the validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java  EE  @Size Validation annotation with Spring (but you must have a Java EE validation API implementor on the classpath, i.e hibernate ). With hibernate, you can import this dependency using maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Then the entire thing becomes:

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class TestController {

@GetMapping("/test")
public void test(@RequestParam(value = "a", required = true )  @Size(min=1) String a, 
@RequestParam(value = "b", required = true) @Size(min=1)   String b) {
     {

     }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Java you can pass only constants as parameters of any annotation. 
That's why it's impossible to do it this way. 
However, you can validate all that kind of things in the method itself.