# How to make the second @RequestParam as mandatory when we have a value for first @RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In Spring Boot we have @RequestParam annotiation. One of the controller method has two request params.
**eg:**

```
@RequestParam String state, @RequestParam String zipCode.
```

Once some value is entered for state, then zipCode has to be made as mandatory. In Java Code we can verify this by using the if condition.

```
if (state != null && zipCode == null)
```

But how to handle it throught the spring concept? Do we have any annotaion or something else? How to achieve this?

Comment: did you try this? @RequestParam(required = true)

Comment: I would suggest to check this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514014/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-assign-the-value-of-required-in-requestparam

Comment: @Lakshman By default it will be true. Mine is scenario basis, like once value has been entered for state, then zipCode should be made as mandatory. while state is not entered, then we don't need to care about zipCode

Comment: @Echoinacup the only upvoted answer is using AOP, is it advised to use AOP here?

Comment: @user7294900 it is not advised it depends on the use case. In the answer you can check several options. Intercepter, programatic way as well

Comment: seems as a simple check as `if (state != null && zipCode == null)`

Comment: I've used the spring validation framework for this. Implement the `org.springframework.validation.Validator` interface and trigger the validation using a `@InitBinder` annoted method in your controller. Your validator impl can do just about anything then. Sadly, its not as nice as just using validation annotations.

Comment: so what is final solution? @JeevaD

Answer (score 1):

Add below dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Add @Validated on controller level then do the validation as below.

For above case `@NotBlank` only enough we can stop at controller level if any empty value reach at controller.

```
 (@RequestParam("state") @Min(5) @Max(10) @NotNull @NotBlank String 
 state);
```

Comment: What about the question? Conditonal required zipCode

Comment: Conditional required things automatically handle by spring by default required = true in request Param. For an exmple from front end user can send empty value then it will reach as empty for that we can use @NotBlank annotation and stop at controller level no need further null check